# Why is $f\in C_0^{\infty}(a,b)$ equivalent to $\exists\epsilon>0\ :\ \forall x\in(-\infty,a+\epsilon)\cup(b-\epsilon,+\infty)$ s.t. $f(x)=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Why is $f\in C_0^{\infty}(a,b)$ equivalent to $\exists\epsilon>0\ :\ \forall x\in(-\infty,a+\epsilon)\cup(b-\epsilon,+\infty)$ s.t. $f(x)=0$?

And why cna't $f$ be just $C_0(a,b)$ or $C_0^1(a,b)$ or even $C_0^k(a,b)$ for some $k$?

This is a function that has all those properties and I guess there exists some $\epsilon$ such that the support is ... but even with this function it is not obvious.

[image]

This is the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and there is certainly no $\epsilon$ such that the property is true.

[image]

Comment: Usually we distinguish between $C^\infty_c$ which has this property by definition and $C^\infty_0$ which doesn't. (This property is called having support compactly contained in $(a,b)$.) Conventions vary somewhat among authors though.

Comment: I thought $C_0$ already meant compact support
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: Wikipedia is not using standard notations. There is a difference between $C_c^{\infty}$ and $C_0^{\infty}$.

Comment: Let's assume that $C_0^\infty(a,b)$ denotes $C^\infty$ functions with compact support in $(a,b)$. Then your statement simply does not hold. $f = \chi_{[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon]}$ is an easy counterexample ($\chi$ denotes the indicator function here). I think what you want to ask is why: $f \in C_0^\infty(a,b)$ is equivalent to $\exists \epsilon>0$: $\forall x \in [a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon]^c$ it holds that $f(x) = 0$ and $f \in C^\infty$.

Comment: Yes I guess you're right

Comment: Alright, then you simply have to prove that every compact subset of $(a,b)$ is a subset of $[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon>0$.